# Transcode SVG to PNG and add metadata using JAVA

Tags: java, svg, metadata, javax.imageio, batik

I'm using Apache Batik for transcoding. Is there any way I could configure the transcoder so it would add some custom metadata to the PNG file output?

Answer (score 0):

Not tried this, but how about extending the `PNGTranscoder`, and override the `writeImage` method to do what you want?

Also, you could use my [SVG ImageIO plugin](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#scalable-vector-graphics-svg) (that also uses Batik), and just write a PNG using standard ImageIO.

To write custom metadata using ImageIO for any of the cases, you would have to obtain the proper `ImageWriter` for `"PNG"` format, get its default metadata (`ImageWriter. getDefaultImageMetadata(..)`), and add your custom metadata to it (don't forget to invoke `IIOMetadata.mergeTree(...)` when done). Write image and metadata in one go, using the `ImageWriter.write(..)` method that takes an `IIOImage` as parameter.